# Android - Bitmap.CreateBitmap - null pointer exception

Tags: c#, android, bitmap, xamarin, xamarin.android

Sometimes when I am trying to create blurred bitmap I am getting "Null Pointer Exception".

Happens in this block of code (I recently started catching the exception so at least it doesn't crash the app):

```
try
{
    using (Bitmap.Config config = Bitmap.Config.Rgb565) {
        return Bitmap.CreateBitmap (blurredBitmap, width, height, config);
    }
}
catch (Java.Lang.Exception exception)
{
    Util.Log(exception.ToString());
}
```

Please refer to these pictures for more details about parameters I am passing into the "CreateBitmap" method:

[image]

Here is the expanded parameters:

[image]

Full exception:

> exception {Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Exception of type
>   'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown.   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2058/58099c53/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61
>   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (IntPtr jclass,
>   IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00064] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2058/58099c53/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1301
>   at Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap (System.Int32[] colors, Int32
>   width, Int32 height, Android.Graphics.Config config) [0x00088] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2058/58099c53/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-22/src/generated/Android.Graphics.Bitmap.cs:735
>   at Psonar.Apps.Droid.PayPerPlay.StackBlur.GetBlurredBitmap
>   (Android.Graphics.Bitmap original, Int32 radius) [0x00375] in
>   d:\Dev\psonar\Source\Psonar.Apps\Psonar.Apps.Droid\Psonar.Apps.Droid.PayPerPlay\Utilities\StackBlur.cs:123
>   --- End of managed exception stack trace --- java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:687)     at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:707)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
>   } Java.Lang.NullPointerException

Not sure if this could be a bug in Xamarin or the passed parameters are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a reply from one of the members of the Xamarin team - Jonathan Pryor:

> The NullPointerException is coming from Java code:
>
> > at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:687)
> >     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:707)
> >     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
>
> Looking quickly at a variety of releases, Jelly Bean might fit:
>
> https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/jb-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#L687
>
> > ```
> >     return nativeCreate(colors, offset, stride, width, height,
> >                         config.nativeInt, false);
> > ```
>
> A quick glance at the surrounding method body shows that `config`
>   isn't checked for null-ness, so if `null` is passed this would result
>   in a NullPointerException.
>
> The problem, though, is that you're not passing null:
>
> ```
> using (Bitmap.Config config = Bitmap.Config.Rgb565) {
>     return Bitmap.CreateBitmap (blurredBitmap, width, height, config);
> }
> ```
>
> ...or are you?
>
> I would suggest that you *remove* the `using` block:
>
> ```
> return Bitmap.CreateBitmap (blurredBitmap, width, height,
>         Bitmap.Config.Rgb565);
> ```
>
> Here's what I think may be happening, but first, a digression:
>
> Deep in the core of Xamarin.Android there is a mapping between Java
>   objects and their corresponding C# wrapper objects. Constructor
>   invocation, Java.Lang.Object.GetObject(), etc. will create
>   mappings; Java.lang.Object.Dispose() will remove mappings.
>
> A core part of this is Object Identity: when a Java instance is
>   exposed to C# code and a C# wrapper is created, the *same* C# wrapper
>   instance should continue to be reused for that Java instance.
>
> An implicit consequence of this is that *any* instance is effectively
>   *global*, because if multiple code paths/threads/etc. obtain a JNI handle to the same Java instance, they'll get the same C# wrapper.
>
> Which brings us back to my hypothesis, and your code block:
>   Bitmap.Config is a Java enum, meaning each member is a Java object.
>   Furthermore, they're global values, so every thread has access to
>   those members, meaning the C# Bitmap.Config.Rgb565 instance is
>   effectively a global variable.
>
> A global variable that you're Dispose()ing.
>
> Which is "fine", in that the *next* time Bitmap.Config.Rgb565 is
>   access, a new wrapper will be created.
>
> The problem, though, is if you have multiple threads accessing
>   Bitmap.Config.Rgb565 at the ~same time, each of which is trying to
>   Dispose() of an instance. At which point it's entirely plausible that
>   the two threads may reference the *same* wrapper instance, and the
>   Dispose() from one thread will thus INVALIDATE the instance used by
>   the other thread.
>
> Which would result in `null` being passed to the Bitmap.createBitmap()
>   call, which is precisely what you're observing.
>
> Please try removing the `using` block, and see if that helps matters.

[The whole thread is accessible here.](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33996)

Then I asked:

> Jonathan Pryor - cheers for the suggestion. My question is that if I
>   remove the using statement, will it introduce a memory leak? Meaning
>   if I stop disposing the new config instance?

He replied:

> That's what GC's are for!
>
> (insert coughing and laughter here.)
>
> We can quibble quite a bit. I'll argue that it is NOT a memory leak,
>   because the memory is well rooted and well known; constantly accessing
>   the Bitmap.Config.Rgb565 will return the previously created instance,
>   not constantly create new instances. There is no "leak," as such.
>
> I'll instead argue that the instance, and the underlying GREF, is a
>   "tax"; it's "burnt", part of the cost of doing business. While it
>   would be "nice" to minimize these costs, it isn't practical to remove
>   all of them (e.g. we "lose" a GREF per class via .class_ref,
>   which is used to lookup method IDs...), at least not with the current
>   architecture.
>
> (I also can't think of an alternate architecture that would result in
>   different costs/"taxes". While I do have some thoughts on allowing
>   things to be improved for some areas, they're not huge.)
>
> I would suggest not worrying about Bitmap.Config.Rgb565 and similar
>   members too much, unless/until the profiler or GREF counts show
>   otherwise.